# Creating a stand-alone site from a WordPress sub site

Tags: multisite, themes

A friend of mine set up a WordPress sub site for me over three years ago as part of her own site. Although I have full control of the page and blog contents I cannot change the theme or the blog layout. The site really needs refreshing now and, though I have the confidence to do this myself, I feel the only way I can do it is by being given total access to her site - something I feel uncomfortable with.
Is there any way I can make my sub site a site in its own right without changing the URL or losing any content?

Comment: Set yourself up with a local test install where you can work on the project. Once you are done, move the site from wordpress.com to the new url, upload the new theme and your done. There are plenty tutorials and instructions out there about local test installs and moving a site from wordpress.com

Answer (score 0):

Basically all you need to do is to import all the posts/pages from the sub-site to a new URL.

1. First you will need to setup a new, fresh WP install e.g
   example.local (on localhost),
2. then you need to export all the contents from your website (e.g example.com) on remote server,
3. finally import all the contents (using XML file from step 2) to example.local

Once you have finished step 3, and eveything looks right, you can

4. move domain example.com to your own server,
5. export the script and database from example.local,
6. and import them to the server,

and if things went smooth, you can ask your friend to remove the subsite from her site.